# How do I add entities/ types on Google Actions in bulk using a csv or a json?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant

I am creating an google assistant app on Actions builder and I have some use cases which convert the company name to their codes. For example, `BMW` becomes `BMWG.DE`.

In actions builder, under the Types section I can see a way to add entries:

[image]

The problem is that the list is VERY long and I can not find a way to upload this list using a csv or a json. On dialogflow one can upload these Entities/ Types in bulk using a csv or JSON which is quite cool.

Does someone knows how to do it or is it not supported on google actions builder?

I can not migrate the `dialogflow` entity list to `actions` as it is a one time migration(quite angry on that) and I have used it already.

Answer (score 1):

Project in Actions Builder are backed by a YAML-based file structure in Actions SDK. If you [`pull` your project](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/gactions) to a local environment, you can convert your JSON entities to [types](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/types) using a [YAML structure](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Type) and then `push` the changes back.

Example type:

```yaml
synonym:
  entities:
    "0":
      synonyms:
      - first
    "1":
      synonyms:
      - second
    "2":
      synonyms:
      - third
  matchType: EXACT_MATCH
```